# MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE always save picture with different name

Tags: android

I am trying to save an image by taking the picture then load it into my application. But the problem I am facing is the picture always saved with different names so I failed to load it. (I check my file manager and i saw the picture I took saved with different names.)

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
    }
    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if (photoFile != null) {
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RESULT_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = "puzzle";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

I cant identify why it always save with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant identify why it always save with different names.

Because you told it to, by [using `createTempFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29). The **point** behind using `createTempFile()` is to create a `File` with a unique filename. If you do not want a unique filename, do not use `createTempFile()`.